# For a != if statement i am getting ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

Hey I am running this for loop and running into the error

```
for j in range(y_hat.shape[0]):
    if(np.not_equal(y_hat[j],y[j])):
        print(j)
        non_match_indexes.append(j)`
```

```
<ipython-input-96-b9feb96de0a0> in PLA(w, x, y, maxIter)

          9 
         10         for j in range(y_hat.shape[0]):
    ---> 11             if(np.not_equal(y_hat[j],y[j])):
         12                 print(j)
         13                 non_match_indexes.append(j)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Try [`np.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
if np.any(y_hat[j] != y[j]):
    # Code
```

This code considers both `y_hat[j]` and `y[j]` are `np.array`s with similar `shape`.
If you are checking for scalars, plain-old `if y_hat[j] != y[j]` would suffice.